# How to get annotation from method through reflection

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

Suppose there is a class

```
public class A {

    @Deprecated
    public void f() {}
}
```

I want to get all the annotations of the method f() through reflection.

What I tried:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class c = A.class;
        Method[] methods = c.getDeclaredMethods();

        String s = methods[0].getDeclaredAnnotations()[0].toString();
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

The problem is that it prints full name of the annotation - @java.lang.Deprecated()

Is there any way to get only short form of the annotation(@Deprecated or just Deprecated)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the `Annotation` instance's type with `getClass()`. This will return a proxy class because it is generated at runtime. This instance will implement the annotation type. So you can get it with `getInterfaces()`.

```
s.getClass().getInterfaces()[0]
```

You can then call `getSimpleName()` on the `Class` instance returned.

Comment: it's something strange: $Proxy1

Comment: @EdisonMiranda Forgot about that. Edited.