# Java: check if a test method has some specific annotation

Tags: java, junit, automation, annotations

Sample code:

```
public class BaseTest {
  @BeforeTest
  // check if the tests have annotation `someAnnotation`
  // if true
  //   foo()
  // else 
  //   do nothing
}
```

```
public class TestCase extends BaseTest {
  @Test
  public void test1() {
    // do something
  }

  @someAnnotation()
  @Test
  public void test2() {
    // do something
  }

  ...
  (some other tests)
  ...

  @someAnnotation()
  @Test
  public void test7() {
    // do something
  }

}
```

I have some tests that extend a base class and would like to enable some code ONLY IF the test has some specific annotation.

In this case, I am looking for the annotation `someAnnotation`. Only `test2()` and `test7()` are annotated, so `foo()` will be executed for them, but not for other methods.

Comment: duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26725788/how-to-get-annotation-from-method-through-reflection

Comment: @Kaan Yes, that is similar with my question. thank you!